# translate SVG striped pattern into d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a chart I'm constructing in d3, and I'd like to include a striped bar in spots.  I have a test version of the bar working in SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="diagonalStripes" x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
         <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="15" style="stroke:none; fill:purple;" />
         <rect x="2" y="0" width="2" height="15" style="stroke:none; fill:green;" />
        <rect x="4" y="0" width="2" height="15" style="stroke:none; fill:red;" />
        <rect x="6" y="0" width="2" height="15" style="stroke:none; fill:yellow;" />
      </pattern>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="5" height="15" style="fill:url(#diagonalStripes);"></rect>
</svg>
```

But when I attempt to translate the information between the  tags into d3 only the first bar (the purple one) shows up:

```
 svg.append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'diagonalStripes')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
    .attr('width', 8)
    .attr('height', 8)
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:purple;")
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x",2)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:yellow;")
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x",4)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:red;") 
    .append('rect') 
    .attr("x",6)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:green;"); 

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr('fill', 'url(#diagonalStripes)')
```

Obviously d3 doesn't handle appending multiple rectangles to a single pattern, but how should I format that first section correctly in order to get the striped bar I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
svg.append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'diagonalStripes')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
    .attr('width', 8)
    .attr('height', 8)
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:purple;")
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x",2)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:yellow;")
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x",4)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:red;") 
    .append('rect') 
    .attr("x",6)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('height', 15)
    .attr('style',"stroke:none; fill:green;");
```

Do it this way:

```
 var defs = svg.append('defs')
   .append('pattern')
   .attr('id', 'diagonalStripes')
   .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
   .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
   .attr('width', 8)
   .attr('height', 8);
 //to def add rect.
 defs
   .append('rect')
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr('width', 2)
   .attr('height', 15)
   .attr('style', "stroke:none; fill:purple;");
 defs
   .append('rect')
   .attr("x", 2)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr('width', 2)
   .attr('height', 15)
   .attr('style', "stroke:none; fill:yellow;");


 defs
   .append('rect')
   .attr("x", 4)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr('width', 2)
   .attr('height', 15)
   .attr('style', "stroke:none; fill:red;");

 defs.append('rect')
   .attr("x", 6)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr('width', 2)
   .attr('height', 15)
   .attr('style', "stroke:none; fill:green;");
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0oM1MvLKjHcRNWBFjBAj?p=preview)

The problem with your approach is that you are appending a rectangle DOM inside another rectangle.
Like first you make a pattern then you add a rect DOM inside the pattern DOM. Later you add the next rect DOM inside the first created rect DOM so on.

Comment: Thanks.  And thank you for the explanation of why my approach wasn't working.  i appreciate you taking the time to explain what exactly was going on.